# Making tikz-cd blend in better with text around it

Tags: tikz-cd

I'm trying to use tikz-cd to write category theory maps within text, like  `Let \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small] A \arrow[r] & B \end{tikzcd} be a map.`, but whenever I do so, there is some unnecessary spacing between the map and the text around it, like this:

[image: Map within text]

It wasn't much of a problem until I had to write images of maps like `Im(\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small] A \arrow[r] & B \end{tikzcd})` and the space between the map and the parenthesis became way too noticeable, looking like this:

[image: Image of the map]

Is there any way to make the tikz-cd maps blend better with the text around it, rather than having this weird space whenever it appears in the middle of it?

Comment: Hi and welcome. `\begin{tikzcd}[cramped]` is the official option for spacing inline tikz-cd.

Comment: Hello, thanks! And awesome, that's just the thing I needed, thanks!

Comment: Do you need `tikz-cd` for this to begin with?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but is there any other better way for this? I like it tikz-cd because there is a quick way to build diagrams on it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `cramped*` style that sets the right `sep` settings so that the resulting CD resembles `A \to B` as close as possible.

This means:

- No `sep`s for the internal TikZ `\matrix`.
- No `sep`s for the cells' nodes (labels along an arrow are a different thing).
- The `outer sep` of the cells' nodes *should* be the width of `\thickmuskip` (≈ `\;`, the pading around `\to`) but something goes wrong there hence the correction factor of `1.25`.
- A `column sep` that's the width of `\to` including the padding.
- Round line cap (as with the `\to` symbol).
- Arrows that do not contribute to the bounding box.

The last one is probably unnecessary for most cases and might be a bad idea for CDs but then again, more complex arrows won't look good inside math-mode anyway, I guess.

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{
  cramped*/.style={
    arrows=overlay, line cap=round,
    every matrix/.append style={
      every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=+0pt}},
    every cell/.append style={inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=1.25*width("$\;$")},
    column sep/.evaluated=width("${}\to{}$")}}
\begin{document}
Let $A \to B$ be a map. (\texttt{\textbackslash to})\par
Let \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small] A \arrow[r] & B \end{tikzcd}
  be a map. (\texttt{column sep=small})\par
Let \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small, cramped] A \arrow[r] & B \end{tikzcd}
  be a map. (\texttt{column sep=small, cramped})\par
Let $A \to B$ be a map. (\texttt{\textbackslash to})\par
Let \begin{tikzcd}[cramped*] A \arrow[r] & B \end{tikzcd}
be a map. (\texttt{cramped*})\par
Let \begin{tikzcd}[cramped*]
  A \ar[r, bend left] \ar[r, bend right, <-] & B
\end{tikzcd} be a map.\par

\[\sin( \begin{tikzcd}[cramped*]
            A \ar[r, bend left] \ar[r, bend right, <-]
          & B
        \end{tikzcd})\]
\[\sin( \begin{tikzcd}[cramped*] A \rar & B \end{tikzcd})\]
\[\sin(A \to B)\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]