# Row spacing and arrow length in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

In the source below, how should I modify the macro `Func`, which uses `tikz-cd`, so that it reproduces the output from the macro `func`, which uses just the `array` environment?

In particular, how should I:

1. Control the row spacing with the `tikz-cd` version to robustly reproduce the row spacing from the `array` version?
2. How do I shorten the arrows in the `tikz-cd` version so as to match the lengths in the `array` version (and position the nodes in the `tikz-cd` version so they are positioned the same way as the "X", "Y" and "x", "f(x)" items in the `array` version?

As to (2), I tried to include option `shorten=1em` in each `\ar` command, but that produces weird results; and I tried to include instead `scalearrow={0.5}{start}{end}` but that creates a tikzcd error.

Note that I want to make the necessary modifications only within the macro `Func`, so that they do *not* affect other instances of the `tizkcd` environment!

*Aim:* Although the `array` version works well (especially since I also have variants of it to allow different kinds of vertical alignment then the items have different lengths), I want to try a `tikz-cd` version so as to facilitate additional "decoration" with `tikz` constructs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    >={Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
    commutative diagrams/arrow style=tikz
  }
\newcommand{\from}{\protect\colon}

% version using array:
\newcommand{\func}[6][]{%
\arraycolsep=0pt
\begin{array}[#1]{rlcl}
{#2} \from\, &{#3}&\,\to\,    &\,{#4}\\
            &{#5}&\,\mapsto\,&\,{#6}
\end{array}}

% version using tikz-cd:
\newcommand{\Func}[6][]{%
\begin{tikzcd}[
ampersand replacement=\&, 
row sep=-4pt,
column sep = small,
/tikz/column 1/.append style = {nodes = {anchor=base east}}
]
{#2 \from #3} \ar[r] \& {#4}\\
            {#5} \ar[r, mapsto] \& {#6}
\end{tikzcd}}

\begin{document}
\[
\func{f}{X}{Y}{x}{f(x)}
\]

\[
\Func{f}{X}{Y}{x}{f(x)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Map between sets and mapto between elements]

Comment: Why trying to do it with `tikz-cd`?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want. If you want to achieve the exact same result produced with `array` and `\to` arrows, then use `Computer Modern Rightarrow` instead of `Straight Barb` and adjust lengths locally instead of options to the environment. To shorten the arrows use the `shorten` key, and to extend them (as you surly need in the `mapsto` arrow) give a negative value to the key.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are really trying to achieve here, but if you are just trying to match the arrows `\to` and `\mapsto` to that in the `tikz-cd` fashion, then you may consider changing them to `\tikz\draw[->](0,0)--(.3,0);` and `\tikz\draw(0,0)edge[commutative diagrams/mapsto](.3,0);`, respectively. (In the code below I modified your `\func`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    >={Straight Barb[scale=0.8]},
    commutative diagrams/arrow style=tikz
  }
\newcommand{\from}{\protect\colon}

% version using array:
\newcommand{\func}[6][]{%
\arraycolsep=0pt
\begin{array}[#1]{rrll}
{#2} \from\, &{#3}& \;\tikz\draw[->](0,0)--(.3,0);\, &\,{#4}\\
            &{#5}& \;\tikz\draw(0,0)edge[commutative diagrams/mapsto](.3,0);\,&\,{#6}
\end{array}}

% version using tikz-cd:
\newcommand{\Func}[6][]{%
\begin{tikzcd}[
ampersand replacement=\&,
row sep=-4pt,
column sep = small,
/tikz/column 1/.append style = {nodes = {anchor=base east}}
]
{#2 \from #3} \ar[r] \& {#4}\\
            {#5} \ar[r, mapsto] \& {#6}
\end{tikzcd}}

\begin{document}
\[
\func{f}{X}{Y}{x}{f(x)}
\]

\[
\Func{f}{X}{Y}{x}{f(x)}
\]

\[
\func{f}{X}{YYYYYYYYY}{x}{f(x)}
\]

\[
\Func{f}{X}{YYYYYYYYY}{x}{f(x)}
\]
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, since the arrow length in the `tikz-cd` version depends on the width of the entries, to match the arrow length, you may need to changing the column width to a fixed value. However, it would be hard to have an appropriate value that works in all situations.

Comment: I want the arrows in the `tikz-cd` version to be the same as those in my *non*-`tikz`-using original `func`, and the vertical alignments in the `tikz-cd` version to be the same as those in my original `func`. Your `Func` does not do that.

Comment: @murray Actually I didn’t modify your `\Func`, I was just changing the arrows in your `\func` to match that of the `tikz-cd` version. I don’t think there is a practical way for `tikz-cd` to use fixed-width arrows since this is not what `tikz-cd` was designed for. Why do you insist on using `tikz-cd` for this propose?

Comment: You *did modify my `array`-using `func` by including `tikz` commands in them. I'm asking about using `tikz-cd` for the reason I stated in the "Aim" paragraph I already had added to my OP.

Comment: @murray Could you please be more specific about *additional decoration with* Ti*k*Z *constructs*? If you let us know what you want explicitly perhaps we can find a way to achieve it directly.

Answer (score 1):

A few settings borrowed from [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665790).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, cd}
\newcommand{\from}{\protect\colon}

% version using array:
\newcommand{\func}[6][]{%
  \begingroup
    \arraycolsep=0pt
    \begin{array}[#1]{@{}r@{}l@{}}
      #2 \from #3 & {}\to #4 \\
               #5 & {}\mapsto #6
    \end{array}
  \endgroup
}

% version using tikz-cd:
\newcommand{\Func}[6][]{%
  \begin{tikzcd}[
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    cells={inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=1.25*width("$\;$")},
    column sep/.evaluated=width("${}\to{}$"),
%    row sep={1.2em,between origins},
    row sep=.27em,
    /tikz/column 1/.append style={anchor=base east},
    /tikz/column 2/.append style={anchor=base west},#1]
    {#2 \from #3} \ar[r] \& {#4}\\
             {#5} \ar[r, mapsto] \& {#6}
  \end{tikzcd}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
\func{f}{X}{Y}{x}{f(x)}
\]
%\vspace{-3.25em}
\[
\Func{f}{X}{Y}{x}{f(x)}
\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]