# How to draw a simple angled arrow inside of an equation?

Tags: arrows, tikzmark

I am wondering what the code is for a simple arrow that points from one part of an equation to another, like so. I have spent a few hours looking for ways to do this and unfortunately have not made very much progress.

[image]

[image]

The code for the math equation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
M:\Sigma^{*}\to\delta(q,s)\to\mu(\delta)\to T_\text{N}\to\Lambda_\mu(\Gamma_0)
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE!!! Take a look at this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34452/arrow-between-parts-of-equation-in-latex

Comment: What is your minimal complete code?

Comment: At the moment it is
`\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
M:\Sigma^{*}\to \tikzmark{a}\delta(q,s)\to\mu(\delta)\to T_\text{N}\to \Lambda_\mu\tikzmark{b}(\Gamma_0)

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,out=315,in=225,distance=0.4cm]

\draw[->,] (a.center) to (b.center);
 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is using the `tikzmark` library, for which you can draw anything on math formulae. The code is from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628856/140722).

[image]

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628856/140722
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{lipsum} %>>> for dummy text only
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\vspace*{2mm}  % a gap for tikzmark later. Change as you wish
    
\[M:\Sigma^{*}\to
\tikzmarknode{stop}{\delta}
(q,s)\to\mu(\delta)\to T_\text{N}\to 
\tikzmarknode{start}{\Lambda_\mu(\Gamma_0)}
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[-stealth,magenta,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt] 
(start)--+(90:.6)-|(stop); 
\end{tikzpicture}   
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `tikz-cd`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=5mm]
M\colon\Sigma^*\arrow[r] & \delta(q,s)\arrow[r] & \mu(\delta)\arrow[r] & T_N\arrow[r] & \Lambda_{\mu}(\Gamma_0)\arrow[lll, to path={-- ([yshift=2ex]\tikztostart.north)-|(\tikztotarget)}]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: With this [`cramped*` style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665790/16595) (but without `overlay`) the `\arrow[r]` has more or less the same spacing as `\to`.

Comment: Good point @Qrrbrbirlbel.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your drawing I made this answer:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{,arrows.meta,matrix,positioning,calc,fit}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \matrix[matrix of math nodes] (P) at (0,0) {M:\Sigma^{*} \to    &   \delta(q,s)\to  &   \mu(\delta)\to  &   T_\text{N}\to   &   \Lambda_\mu(\Gamma_0)   \\};
        \draw[thick, red, -{Stealth}, shorten <=2mm] (P-1-5) |- (2,1) -| ([xshift=-5mm] P.north -|P-1-2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Using the `matrix` library of TikZ you can target every cell as a node. Those can be used to draw an arrow in between two nodes of that matrix. The positioning defaults to the middle of those nodes, but can be altered.

[image: matrix_arrow]